# int value to Hex and put it in int array

Tags: c#, arrays, int, hex

i have this code

```
int[] i = new int[2]
i[0] = 0x13;
i[1] = 0x88;
```

here a value 5000 is converted to hex (1388) and put in an int array.

I want to make it so i can put in what i want with a int parameter. E.g. ``var represents decimal 6000 and it should convert it to hex (1770) and end up as

```
int[] i = new int[2]
i[0]= 0x17
i[1]= 0x70
```

in the array.

Comment: Which programming language would you like to use? Adding a proper programming language tag might help you with getting answers. Also, always post what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Im using C# and have no idea how to solve it. I manualy set the value in i[0] and i[1] now, but would like to do it as i said above.

Comment: Are you looking for the BitConverter class? You can convert simple types to byte array with it.. see MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            UInt16 input = 0x7017;
            byte[] i = new byte[2];
            i[0] = (byte)(input & 0xff);
            i[1] = (byte)((input >> 8) & 0xff);​
```